# react checkbox not updating properly (sematic ui)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

This is weird, simple checkbox component state changes, prop does not and UI does not update!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class UiCheckBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            label: '',
            checked: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Checkbox label={this.props.label} name={this.props.name} checked={this.props.checked} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        );
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
        });
        console.log("prop:" + this.props.checked);
        console.log("state:" + !this.state.checked);
    }
}
```

If i change

```
checked={this.props.checked}
```

To this

```
checked={this.state.checked}
```

It works, but I cant set the initial value of the checkbox, what am I doing wrong, PS i'm certain this was working earlier[honest] ?

This is how I'm using it.

```
<UiCheckBox name={"Tea"} label={"Tea"} checked={false} />
```

Idea's anyone ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `handleChange()` only changes `this.state.checked`. `this.state.checked` is not used in your `render()` method. Therefore, no visible change occurs.

If you want to change `props`: you'll have to pass a `function` that `updates` the `original data store`.

Else: you can set `default state` using `props`.

See below for a practical example

```js
// Check Box.
class CheckBox extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {checked: this.props.checked}

  // Render.
  render() {
    const {checked} = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <label>{`${checked}`}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={this.toggle}/>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
  
  // Toggle.
  toggle = event => this.setState(state => ({checked: !state.checked}))
  
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<CheckBox checked={true}/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: HI Arman, thanks for the super fast response, I see your setting the state to the props, that's what i needed to set it to the incoming, think i need to read up some more on states and prop's, thanks